# Expanded widget getting shrinked whenever I remove flexible widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple layout which consists of column, container and sized box. Here is the code:

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, right: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    radius: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Todoey List",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 50
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "1 items",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15))
                    ),
                    //child: TaskScreen(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Whenever I add `Flexible` widget around `Sized box` then I get like this:

[image: error]

But whenever I remove the flexible widget then I get like this(expected behaviour):
[image: normal]

Why is the `Flexible` widget shrinking even when there is enough space?

Why is the white container getting small whenever I add `Flexible` widget?

Comment: I can't test this without `AddTaskScreen()` in the code. Also, may I ask why would you want to wrap the `SizedBox` inside a `Flexible` widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what the expanded widget does? If you do, do you know what the flexible widget does?

Expanded tells its child to occupy as much space as available, Flexible tells its child to occupy as much space as available (or less), that is to say, in this context Flexible and Expanded do **the same thing**.

The only difference between Flexible and Expanded is that flexible has some extra options which you aren't using.

Still, with that information, your layout should not look like it does, it is quite a weird error indeed, however, I know why you get this error:

`Flexible`, as I established, tells its child to use as much space as available, `SizedBox` on the other hand, tells itself to use an exact amount of space, so the flexible tries to expand the `sizedbox` to be of about 1/4 of the available space (because there are three flexible widgets and one expanded, meaning each should take 1/4 of the remaining space) but it can't because the `sizedbox` refuses to have a different size than the one you gave it.

However, the only widget that can size itself is the Expanded widget, so it uses its fourth of the available space, that is why the expanded widget becomes small, it expects to use all the available space, but it doesn't because of the sized boxes.

The solution? Well, you said it yourself! Simply remove the Flexible widget from the SizedBoxes and the layout will act as it should. Another solution would be to not specify a height on the boxes, in order to let the Flexible widget size them itself, but this is most likely not what you want because it will make your spacing take as much space as your white container.

Comment: Then how to resize the elements if keyboard is present. I used sized box inside flexible and it was working the way I wanted. If the screen is normal then all sized boxes have same height. If keyboard comes up then sized boxes shrink. Here is the link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aditya425/Flash-chat/master/lib/screens/registration_screen.dart

Comment: For eg: take the sized box with height 70. It remains height 70 if there is no obstruction on screen. If keyboard comes up then the sized box will shrink

Comment: I see, that does complicate things a bit more, have you tried using box constraints to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: It worked when I increased the flex value of expanded widget